# display cookie immediately

Tags: php, cookies

iam creating a php website in which i want to create a changable background color .. 
 so i created a `$_GET['color']` variable .. if the user click red the url will be `http://localhost/?color=red` and it sets a cookie with the chosen color 
my proplem that if the user clicks for example yellow the browser needs to refresh one time to get the new `$_COOKIE['color']` to change the background color.. i want the to get the $_COOKIE variable to change the background color without any refreshing immediately when the user clicks the yellow link  ??

Comment: You can change the color via js and also set cookie without even using server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `css` to dynamically change the background color of your page.
Actually, you don't even need to contact the server for that, cookies are a client side feature that can be set using javascript.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle demonstrating that: http://jsfiddle.net/JvrVA/

Comment: how i can change it by css dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you want to change the background without refreshing the page? i suggest to use jQuery ( or javascript ) for that.

just be sure you trigger the on click event when you click on the link to change the background. if you use jQuery you can try something like:

```
$('a.yellow').click(function(){
  $('body').css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for getting cookie value

```
  function getCookie(name)
   {
   var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
   }
   var color=getCookie("color");
  </script>
```